# How can I turn an absolute path into a relative path within a function?

Tags: python, path

I'm currently facing the problem that I'm working with different files. Within some of those files are other files - absolute files - I do not want to change them all to relative path since then I'll run into another problem. So my question is whether I can indicate a relative path within a function with e.g. adding two dots. So this is the code snipped:

```
    if not all(np.array(skills_dict['snames']) == df_cube['img_path'].values)
```

So 'img_path' is the absolute path and I would like to make it relative for this function, something quirky like

```
    df_cube['..'+'img_path'].values
```

Maybe someone could help me with that. Highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath

Comment: Every absolute path is also a relative path — relative to the root directory. Turning absolute paths into relative paths isn’t what you after. But you *can* “navigate” inside any path by adding `..` to the end (not the beginning), and appending a new file. Or you use the `pathlib` API for a more modern approach.

Comment: Thanks @olinox14 I looked at the documentation but it's only explaining the usual ways of relative and absolute path. Is there no way to add the dots to the value which is saved in img_path only temporarily?

Comment: @Wupppa Can you give an exact example of what you want? Your current question invites guesswork.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph but I really do not want to append new files, I "just" want to indicate that the path saved in "img_path" is not the complete and that the function needs to look for a relative directory so to speak

Comment: @Wupppa So far that’s the same as what your question text says but, as I already noted, that’s vague and unclear, and uses terminology incorrectly. Please give a *specific* example.

Comment: Please make this a running example, including something that initializes `df_cube` and `skills_dict`. It only has to be a couple of made up rows. Also include the result you want. We don't know what these data structures are, and we don't know what "relative" means. You want a path "/home/someuser/Documents/mydoc.txt" to be "../home/someuser/Documents/mydoc.txt"?

Comment: This question lacks details needed for an answer. Voting to close until OP gives us a running example and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can convert absolute paths to relative paths using `os.path.relpath()`.

I don't quite understand the question actually, but maybe that function can be used to answer it. That function is the one I was after when I landed here via duckduckgo.

Answer (score -3):

you can do something like this. It will return the relative path of absolute_path. You can replace that with whatever absolute path you need to.

```
import os

def get_rel_path(absolute_path):
    """
    Gets the relative path of absolute_path
    """
    return os.path.dirname(absolute_path)
```

Comment: This is a mess: the name, comment and code absolutely do not fit together, the code itself doesn’t make sense, and none of these things seems to be what OP is after.

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: “Exactly”? You can’t know that, since OP’s question is currently incredibly unclear. That said, your code also changed fundamentally from the version I commented on. The current version is more likely similar to what OP wants, but still contains stuff that is probably off (such as `__file__`, and the arbitrarily hard-coded `../..` and `your_path`).

Comment: OP asked for a relative path, this is a relative path.

Comment: First off, you’ve changed your answer **yet again** to do something different. And secondly what your code now does is just the same as `os.path.dirname`, no need for this extra function.